# Como faço para atualizar a foto ? No momento só está salvando na pasta, queria exibir a imagem

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp

```js
        $("#btn_confirmar").click(function () {

            var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('formAlteraFoto'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Usuario/AlterarFoto',
                data: form,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Upload com sucesso!');
                },
                error: function (data, jqXHR, exception) {
                    alert('Erro ao atualizar imgem de perfil!');
                }
            });
        })
```

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AlterarFoto()
        {
            //return RedirectToAction("Clientes");         
            
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                }                
            }
            return RedirectToAction("EditarCliente");
        }
```

Comment: Inclua o código da sua view ou o html redenrizado da mesma.

Comment: Tem que retornar o nome (ou o caminho) da imagem salva no `data` do Ajax e alterar com `$(id ou classe da imagem).attr("src", data);`

Comment: Como assim mano ? Poderia me mostrar ? Não manjo mt de Ajax. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faz o sentido o seu `RedirectToAction("EditarCliente");` quando você faz um post ajax, para o `AlterarFoto()`, que apenas faz o upload do arquivo. Se você inspecionar o retorno dessa requisição pelo browser mesmo, verá que o response é o hmtl inteiro da sua `EditarCliente`.

Além disso você não faz nenhum tratamento para o caso de erros, como por exemplo o já existir um arquivo com esse nome no diretório de destino ou não haver permissão para escrita no mesmo.

Você deveria mudar o `AlterarFoto()` para um `JsonResult`, abaixo segue um exemplo (longe de representar as melhores práticas, mas apenas uma base inicial para o entendimento de como você pode resolver o problema).

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AlterarFoto()
{
    object retorno = null;                
    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                retorno = new
                {
                    imageUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Uploads/" + fileName),
                    sucesso = true,
                    mesagem = string.Empty
                };
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        retorno = new
        {
            imageUrl = string.Empty,
            sucesso = false,
            mensagem = e.Message

        };
    }

    return Json(retorno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Já no seu JavaScript:

```
$("#btn_confirmar").click(function () {

    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('formAlteraFoto'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Usuario/AlterarFoto',
        data: form,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != null && data.sucesso){
                alert('Upload com sucesso!');
                //código para alterar a sua imagem na tela
                $("#seletorDoElemento").attr('src', data.imageUrl);
            }else{
                alert(data.mensagem);
            }

        },
        error: function (data, jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Erro ao atualizar imgem de perfil!');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: É que sou novo na área mano, por isso algumas coisas não fazem sentido..kkk Mas toda dica é bem vinda mano ! ainda mais de boas práticas ! Obrigado.

Comment: Ficou alguma dúvida?

Comment: Não mano, to fazendo as alterações aqui. Mais uma vez obrigado ! (: